# Losing access to memory for all class variables

Tags: c++, memory, glm-math

I have a method in my class that is causing me a world of trouble and I don't understand what is happening. I know that this is the method creating the problem. The error occurs at the if statement in the 3rd line.

Basically I have 2 arrays that hold objects and I just want to calculate the distance between them. The overall class is called ProjectOne and it a subclass of a class called OpenGlApplicationBase. The memory error is causing all of the member variables of the entire class to be unaccessible.

```
for (int i = enemiesOnBoard.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    GlutObject* gObj = enemiesOnBoard.at(i);
    if (gObj->getType().compare("EnemySphere") == 0){
        EnemySphere* s = (EnemySphere*) gObj;
        glm::vec3 enemyPos = s->getWorldPosition();
        //cout << "This is a " << s->getType() << endl;
        for (int j = cannonBallsOnBoard.size() - 1; j >= 0; j--){
            CannonBall* cb = cannonBallsOnBoard.at(i);
            glm::vec3 cbPos = cb->getWorldPosition();
            GLfloat distance =  calcDistance(enemyPos, cbPos);
            cout << distance << endl;
        }
    }
    else if (gObj->getType().compare("EnemyCone") == 0)
    {
        EnemyCone* c = (EnemyCone*) gObj;
        glm::vec3 enemyPos = c->getWorldPosition();
        //cout << "This is a " << c->getType() << endl;
        for (int j = cannonBallsOnBoard.size() - 1; j >= 0; j--){
            CannonBall* cb = cannonBallsOnBoard.at(i);
            glm::vec3 cbPos = cb->getWorldPosition();
            GLfloat distance = calcDistance(enemyPos, cbPos);
            cout << distance << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone see the problem.

Comment: "The memory error is causing all of the member variables of the entire class to be unaccessible.". This makes very little sense. Perhaps you should tell what you are seeing, without any interpretation (e.g. "there is a 'Segmentation fault' message on the console").

Comment: Ah. I didn't see any errors at first, but when I close the call stack I see "Error reading register value" for elapsedTimeSec. I also get 0xC000041D: An unhandled exception was encountered during a user callback,

Class variables look like this.
http://postimg.org/image/hbzd7p1yx/